# Am I able to use textbook questions, for commercial purpose in India?

Tags: intellectual-property, india, academia

There is a demand for solutions of textbook questions, whose solution manuals are not available online.

Let's say I want to start a business creating banks of answers to the questions in these textbooks; then publish them on my website, then collecting fee for there use.

Would this violate any laws or property rights?

Comment: Im new to this site. Please comment along with downvote.

Comment: I will edit or delete according to its scope .

Answer (score 1):

Answering questions and publishing them as a work is making a derivative work. Without license, that is breaking Berne Convention and copyright laws.